# what is wrong with this code ? it's not showing any output after executing

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-multiset

The function must return an array of integers representing the frequency of occurrence of each query string in strings.

matchingStrings has the following parameters:

string strings[n] - an array of strings to search
string queries[q] - an array of query strings

Example

```
strings[]={"ab","ab","abc"}
queries[]={"ab","abc","bc"}
```

the output will be

```
result[]={2,1,0}
```

.

```
vector<int> matchingStrings(vector<string> strings, vector<string> queries) {
   
   
    unordered_multiset<string> m;
    
    int ms=0,l=sizeof(strings)/sizeof(strings[0]),k=sizeof(queries)/sizeof(queries[0]);
    vector<int> res;
    int y;
    
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        m.insert(strings[i]);
    }
    
    for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
        y=(m.count(queries[j]));
        res.push_back(y);
        
    
    }

     return res;
}
```

Comment: `l=sizeof(strings)/sizeof(strings[0]),k=sizeof(queries)/sizeof(queries[0])` -- Where did you get the idea to use this to get the number of entries in a `std::vector`?  This proves that "online competition" sites do not teach proper C++.

Comment: @suryateja the issue seems to be resolved, please mark any of the answers as accepted to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code works. I don't know why you didn't use size() method in vector.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<int> matchingStrings(vector<string> strings, vector<string> queries) {


    unordered_multiset<string> m;

    int ms=0;
    vector<int> res;
    int y;

    for(int i=0;i<strings.size();i++)
    {
        m.insert(strings[i]);
    }
    for(int j=0;j<queries.size();j++)
    {
        y=(m.count(queries[j]));
        res.push_back(y);
    }

    return res;
}
int main() {
    vector <string> strings;
    vector <string> queries;
    strings.push_back("ab");
    strings.push_back("ab");
    strings.push_back("abc");
    queries.push_back("ab");
    queries.push_back("abc");
    queries.push_back("bc");
    for(int item : matchingStrings(strings,queries)){
        cout<<item<<' ';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the sizes of your input vectors wrong, they would be constant with `sizeof` operator at compile-time. Get their sizes/lengths like this:

```
int ms = 0;
std::size_t l = strings.size(), k = queries.size();
```